# Issue in social login with google in vuejs (vueCLI)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-cli, laravel-socialite

I have used frontend in vuejs(vueCLI) and backend in laravel api. I have issue in social login with google in vuejs. I used **vue-social-auth package**. Here is this link (https://forum.vuejs.org/t/laravel-vue-social-auth-spa/54341). I have follow this link code. Login with Google Properly Work. **But I can't get a response in User info like name, email or google_id..** please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your callback controller try to get user data using this code:

```
$platform='google';        
$userData = Socialite::driver($platform)->user();
```

> When You disable session You could use stateless method. The stateless
> method may be used to disable session state verification. This is
> useful when adding social authentication to an API:

```
$platform='google';        
$userData = Socialite::driver($platform)->stateless()->user();
```

Comment: I did use this code but it does not work. getting Laravel error
Then a little bit of change in this code works and I also get a response.
$userData = Socialite::driver($platform)->stateless()->user();

Comment: Both method works but statless method work when You disable session.